# Get formant settings (e.g. f1, f2, f3.. frequencies, bandwidths etc) from human voice

Tags: formants

Is there a way to convert human voice sample to formant voice? May be by extracting peculiarities from waveform? Is there a tool or a program library you can suggest?

Comment: You will have to explain what "formant voice" is. You can compute formant values; you can synthesize formant values into speech. Are you looking fora program that will do LPC analysis?

Comment: I am doing formant speech synthesis and I am looking for a tool to analyze the formants for different phonetics. I found a tool **Praat** http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: No, that is the current standard.